# Emacsclient called by applescript can't find emacs server socket

Tags: emacs, applescript

The shell command

```
emacsclient -n -e '(make-remember-frame)'
```

works.

But the applescript

```
do shell script "emacsclient -n -e '(make-remember-frame)'"
```

just returns

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type \"M-x server-start\".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

--socket-name
--server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
--alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use this, but it has worked successfully in the past for various purposes.  Perhaps you can modify it to suit your needs.  The `init.el` or `.emacs` file must have `(server-start)` inside in order to make everything work.  I have lots of stuff that loads when `Emacs` is activated for the first time, so I need a 5 second delay before `emacsclient` is called -- you can adjust the delay downward if your Emacs loads faster.  If Emacs is already running, there is no need for a delay.  You can comment out the verbal messages generated by `say` -- I used them this morning to test the conditions and make a minor adjustment to the script.  The script contains a command-line example on line 4, which calls two Emacs functions.  Of course, the path to your `Emacs` and `emacsclient` will need to be adjusted to wherever you have installed them on your computer.

```
#  `(server-start)` must be inside `init.el` or `.emacs` file.
#  This script can be used in the terimal:  osascript path-to-script arguments
#  Terminal Example:
#  osascript /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.emacsclient.applescript "-e '(progn (dired \"/Applications\") (message \"Hello-World\!\"))'"

on run argv
    set arg to item 1 of argv
    set emacs to application "Emacs"
    set appIsRunning to emacs is running
    if appIsRunning then
        say "Emacs is already running."
        do shell script "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs_06_01_2014.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient " & arg
    else
    tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs_06_01_2014.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
        say "Please wait five seconds for Emacs to load."
        delay 5
        do shell script "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs_06_01_2014.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient " & arg
    end if
end run
```

Comment: Turns out that it's just the path problem. Simple "emacsclient" from applescript editor will use the default /usr/bin/emacsclient, which sucks. I was inspired by you. Thank you.